# Bash if statement, with a grep from a file -eq 0 from $?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get this little script to work, to tell me if I have one of two options enabled. It seems to work on the first if statement, but doesn't on the next two. Can anyone point me in the right direction to make this work?

EDIT: The purpose of this script was something I could run, to check if tun0 (or any variation of tun existed in an ifconfig output) existed, if it did, I was done, if it didn't, I needed to check to see if one of the other two lines were marked as yes in the "test.ini" file, to see if tun0 missing was anything of concern, or if I could skip past it. Lines 7 and 12 were the area's throwing me for a loop. I am sorry that I didn't have this clarified earlier.

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2
 3 if [[ $(ifconfig|grep -iq tun;echo $?) -eq 0 ]]
 4 then
 5         echo "This unit has tun0"
 6 else
 7         if [[ $(grep -iq enabled=yes test.ini|grep -v "Auto\|Purge\|AD"|awk '{print $1}';echo $?) -eq 1 ]]
 8         then
 9                 echo "This unit has file copy enabled"
 10                 echo "but does not have tun0"
 11         else
 12                 if [[ $(grep -iq AutoSyncEnabled=yes test.ini|grep -v Exchange|awk '{print $1}';echo $?) -eq 1 ]]
 13                 then
 14                         echo "This unit has rsync enabled"
 15                         echo "but does not have tun0"
 16                 else
 17                         echo "No tun0 but no requirement either."
 18                 fi
 19         fi
 20 fi
```

Comment: `awk '{print $1}'` will always return true. I can't even see the point of the awk honestly.

Comment: In line 7, `grep -iq ...` is going to return a "quiet" output. Not sure if this is wanted

Comment: `if [[ $(ifconfig|grep -iq tun;echo $?) -eq 0 ]]` should be something like `if ifconfig | grep -iq tun`.

Comment: `grep|grep|awk` is an anti-pattern! One pipe is definitely useless, probably both.

Comment: You are right, I can take the awk out. However, if I take out the second grep, I get multiple similar lines back (This file has several items that have the same flags, but under different subsections, having them do different things.) If I take the -q out of grep, my if statement fails out, saying that it was expecting a number, but received both a number and a word, but if I do have the -q then it always gives the same output on lines 7 and 12, even though it works on line 3.

Comment: `if [[ $(ifconfig) = *tun* ]]` is equivalent logic, but no silly grep or awk or whatever.

Comment: `tun_devices=( /sys/class/net/tun* ); if [[ -e $tun_devices ]]; then echo "At least one tun device exists; specifically, there are ${#tun_devices[@]} of them."; fi`

Comment: ...or, of course, `[ -e /sys/class/net/tun0 ]`, if you just care about the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting Awk to set its exit code to 1 when there are no matches, but Awk does not do this by default.  You need to do something like

```
awk '{ success ... exit 0 } END { exit 1 }'
```

to explicitly set the exit code.

The `if [[ $(something; echo $?) -eq 0 ]]` is also a massive morass of anti-patterns.  You simply want

```
if something
```

-- examining `$?` is what `if` does; its very purpose.

As per your comment below, you apparently meant `if grep -i something test.ini | something else` without the `-q` (which suppresses any output from `grep`) which can be refactored to

```
if awk '/something/ && ... something else' test.ini
```

except that loses the `-i` flag from `grep`.  The obvious fix is to lowercase the input line (and similarly lowercase the regex, because otherwise you will of course not get a match!) but there are other ways to make Awk make comparisons while ignoring character case.

```
if awk 'tolower($0) ~ /something/ && ... something else' test.ini
```

With those remarks, try this refactored version.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ifconfig | grep -iq tun; then
     echo "This unit has tun0"
elif ! awk 'tolower($0) ~ /enabled=yes/ && !/Auto|Purge|AD/{
        print $1; fail=1} END { exit fail }' test.ini
then
    echo "This unit has file copy enabled"
    echo "but does not have tun0"
elif ! awk 'tolower($0) ~ /autosyncenabled=yes/ && !/Exchange/{
        print $1; fail=1} END { exit fail }' test.ini
then
    echo "This unit has rsync enabled"
    echo "but does not have tun0"
else
    echo "No tun0 but no requirement either."
fi
```

Your Awk scripts will print output to standard output; if that is not desired, take out the `print` and just `exit 0` on the first success, else `END { exit 1 }'`, like this;

```
:
elif awk 'tolower($0) ~ /enabled=yes/ && !/Auto|Purge|AD/{ exit 0 }
        END { exit 1 }' test.ini
then
:
```

Notice also the `elif` to avoid nesting the `if` flow too deeply.

Comment: Really love the use of the elif to avoid the nesting. 
That script for the most part dumped the entire file to my screen though.
The first grep in this, is grepping for any lines with enabled, but since it will return multiple values, that second grep, is using the -v output, so that it is removing the extra values.

grep -i enabled

This returns several lines
AutoBackupEnabled=No        ; Enable/disable Datasweep
PurgeEnabled=No           ;   Remove older files from source directory
AutoSyncEnabled=yes         ; Enable/disable Secure Data Sync.
grep -v removes the extra results I don't want.

Comment: It's not really feasible to troubleshoot this further without access to the precise `ifconfig` output you want to react on and the contents of `test.ini`.  Also your comment isn't very readable; perhaps you should [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: Updated some more based on the understanding that you did not really actually intend to use `grep -q`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding two ways of getting this to work. The route I took, used one of our internal programs to read the file, which gives only the output of yes/no. From that I made the if statement complete using

```
== [Yy]es ]]
```

I also found that I could continue down the rabbit hole I was going, using way too many pipes, to get the output I wanted.

```
if [[ $(grep -i enabled=yes test.ini|grep -v "Auto\|Purge\|AD"|awk '{print $1}'|cut -b 9-11) == [Yy]es ]]
```

However, using the internal program, that reads that file regularly, and having it spit out the output of yes or no, seemed much simpler (and with no pipes/long drawn out statements, etc).

My biggest problem, was as Jens pointed out, too many pipes. Also, as 123 pointed out, I didn't realize that the $? was just what completed on the last pipe, not the entire command.

Thank you all for your help with this. A lot of the information from everyone's comments will help immensely with future scripts, and choices in how I write them.

Comment: `grep | awk` and `awk | cut` remain massive [antipatterns](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)